# Proof of the stacked bases theorem using the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

> (Stacked bases theorem) If $A$ is a finitely generated free abelian group, and $B$ is a subgroup of $A,$ of the same rank, say $m$, then there is a basis $\{a_{i}: 1 \leq i \leq m \}$ of $A$ and there are elements $d_{1},d_{2},\ldots d_{m}$ of $R$ such that $d_{i} | d_{i+1}$ for each $i$ and $\{ d_{i}a_{i}: 1 \leq i \leq m \}$ is a generating set for $B$.

Some books prove the stacked bases theorem before the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian group. But I wonder how to do it conversely.

If we assume the structure theorem for finite abelian group which shows that $A/B$ is a direct sum of at most $m$ cyclic groups. How to use this fact to show the stacked bases theorem above?

Comment: Let me point out that, leaving the condition $d_i\mid d_{i+1}$ aside, your question is essentially what allegedly Marcus asks for in his book  "Number Fields" (exercise 27.(b) in the chapter 2). I say "allegedly" because the exercise states "there is this theorem which says finite abelian groups are products of cyclic groups. Deduce stacked bases theorem" with no indication on _how_ one might use it.

Comment: Possibly the easiest way to see this is to write down a $ \mathbf Z $-linear map $ A \to A $ whose image is $ B $, and put it in Smith normal form. The structure theorem also drops out immediately from this idea.

Comment: @Starfall Although this idea works, I suppose that OP's intent is to try and get a proof _directly_ from the structure theorem without having to use other, intricate or not, ideas.